# .NET Regular Expression to create STRONG password

Tags: .net, regex

Here is the .NET Regular Expression that I am using to create a strong password (which is not correct for my project password requirements):

```
(?=^.{15,25}$)(\d{2,}[a-z]{2,}[A-Z]{2,}[!@#$%&+~?]{2,})
```

Password requirements:

1. Minimum 15 Character (up to 25)
2. Two Numbers
3. Two Uppercase Letters
4. Two Lowercase Letters
5. Two Special Characters  `! @ # $ % & + ~ ?`

They are not required to be beside one another & in the specific order as the Regular Expression that I pasted requires.

The above Regular Expression requires a password like this:  12abCD!@QWertyP

It REQUIRES them in the specific order in the RE... which is not what I want!

This should pass a correctly formatted RE with the specifications listed above: Qq1W!w2Ee#3Rr4@Tt5

How can I remove the necessity for them to be beside one another and in order??
Obviously the password should be random if the person so chooses.

Comment: Why the 25 character upper limit? You're not storing it anywhere are you?

Comment: Sorry for chitchat but would not be smarter to choose minimum password length based on "entropy". For instance - lowcase or upcase  40 characters, lower and upper leters 30, upcase+lowcase+numbesr 25, all printable set 15 characters minimum. I personaly always hate when i have to cose from such restrictions.

Comment: I agree with the other upvoted answers, this is not a good fit for a regex

Comment: Yes, we are storing the password in the database.

I agree with most everyone that this is not a good use for the REGEX and have moved on to a random password generator to provide the password that will be created for the user, e-mailed to them, and stored in the DB.

THANK YOU for your excellent contributions and hard work on this question!

Comment: The password minimum was 15 characters, but I just grabbed an arbitrary number (25) as the upper limit. Not many people want to have a 15 character password, let alone a 25 character.

Answer (score 10):

I think you're looking for more than what a regex was designed to do.

Consider a C#/VB method like this:

```
bool IsStrongPassword( String password )
{
    int upperCount = 0;
    int lowerCount = 0;
    int digitCount = 0;
    int symbolCount = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < password.Length; i++ )
    {
        if ( Char.IsUpper( password[ i ] ) )
            upperCount++;
        else if ( Char.IsLetter( password[ i ] ) )
            lowerCount++;
        else if ( Char.IsDigit( password[ i ] ) )
            digitCount++;
        else if ( Char.IsSymbol( password[ i ] ) )
            symbolCount++;
    }

    return password.Length >= 15 && upperCount >= 2 && lowerCount >= 2 && digitCount >= 2 && symbolCount >= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will be much more readable and maintainable in classic code:

The pseudo-code would be:

```
int count_alpha = 0, count_digit = 0, count_symbol = 0, ...

for each ch in password:
  if is_alpha(ch):
     count_alpha += 1
  elif is_digit(ch):
     count_digit += 1
  ...

if (count_alpha < 2) or (count_digit < 2) or ...
  rejection_message() 
  ...
```

It might be that you're implementing the requirements rather than in a position to influence them, but I'd generally recommend estimating the entrophy and using existing code to do that.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you cannot do that reasonably, meaning you'd have to list all possible order combinations in the regex, which would add up to 24 combinations.

I would do 4 separate checks:

- `\d{2,}`
- `[a-z]{2,}`
- `[A-Z]{2,}`
- `[!@#$%&+~?]{2,}`

Related question: [Variable order regex syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699708/variable-order-regex-syntax)

As an aside, your rules look too cumbersome to me I would reconsider them, for example, to have 3 chars of two of etters, digits or symbols.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?=.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%&+~?].*[!@#$%&+~?]).{15,25}$
```

This regex will do what you want. It will be making up to 5 passes through your password string, but considering what you are doing with it, I don't expect that to be a problem.

Edited to fix a typo that ruined the regex.

Comment: If you expect to be given super-long strings, you could create a variant of this where the check for character count comes first. Since you are matching the entire string anyway, the character count step could be part of a lookahead as well, saving you from having to rewrite any other portion of the expression.

Comment: The list of symbolic characters can be expanded to [!@#$%&+-/`^)(|\=:;.,}{~?]

Answer (score 0):

To require one of each character type, you can use this:

> `(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%&+~?])^.{15,25}$`

I'm not quite sure how to translate that to require two of each character type, though.

Basically, the `?=` matches a suffix to `.*` (i.e. anything), but doesn't capture anything, so you can check that all of the conditions are met specifying order.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be as follow too:

^(?=(.*\d){2,})(?=(.*[a-z]){2,})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2,})(?=(.*[!@#$%&+~?]){2,})).{15,25}$

Comment: This requires the two digits (or others symbols in the same group) to be subsequent, e.g. !%34dfZXaaaaaaaa will work, !%3dfZXaaaaaaaa1 will not.

Answer (score 0):

```
^((?=(.*\d){2,})(?=(.*[a-z]){2,})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2,})(?=(.*[!@#$%&+~?]){2,})).{15,25}$
```

I know this is a year old, but from the few responses, I gathered that this would work.

The top answer is correct except, it just needs a * preceding the pattern.