# asp.net 4.0 regularExpressionValidator

Tags: asp.net, regex, reg-expressionvalidator

I need to modify my regularexpressionvalidator code to require the user to meet the following password requirements:

a. Contains at least 2 uppercase characters: `A, B, C` etc.

b. Contains at least 2 lowercase characters: `a, b, c,` etc.

c. Contains at least 2 numbers: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0`

d. Contains at least 2 special characters, i.e.

```
! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + | ~ - = \ ` { } [ ] : " ; ' < > ? , . /
```

Current code only requires a 10 character password length:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valPassword" 
runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" 
ErrorMessage="Error: 10 character required password length"
ValidationExpression=".{10}.*" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1489337/701062 seems to be pretty close to what you are after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
^(?=^.{10}$)(?=^(.*?[A-Z]){2,}.*?$)(?=^(.*?[a-z]){2,}.*?$)(?=^(.*?\d){2,}.*?$)(?=^(.*?[!@#$%^&]){2,}.*?$).*?$
   --------  ---------------------  --------------------- ------------------- --------------------------
      |               |                       |                    |                      |->checks for 2 or more special characters
      |               |                       |                    |->checks for 2 or more digits 
      |               |                       |->checks for 2 or more small letters
      |               |->checks for 2 or more capital words
      |
      |->checks for 10 words..
```

Comment: @Gary.S i had used this form `^(.*?[a-z]){2,}.*?$`

Comment: My mistake, it works however it has been answered in other questions on the site

Comment: This didn't work for me but put me on the right path. i ended up using: ^((?=(.*\d){2,})(?=(.*[a-z]){2,})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2,})(?=(.*[!@#$%&+~?]){2,})).{10,25}$